# How to stop background video from resizing on scroll on mobile?

Tags: css, video, mobile, background-image

The resizing of the background happens due to the popping in/out of the browser bar on the phone. How can I prevent this issue?

CSS

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I have tried messing with with width, height and position values to no success.

Comment: You can try to use overflow property on both html and body tags : html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Had to change video height to:

```
height: 100vh
```